# Can I bake cake in an air fryer?

Tags: baking, equipment, cake

My oven does not work at the moment, but I have an air fryer.

Is it possible to bake a cake in the air fryer?

Answer (score 2):

You can, absolutely. But it will be tricky.

The unique aspect of an air fryer is its high airflow, which dries out the surface of foods quite quickly. (In a residential kitchen, only a deep fryer comes close to matching that, hence "air fryer".) That's great for crispiness, but for baked goods, you have to consider how much "crispiness" you actually want.

If I had to cook a cake in the air fryer, I would find a recipe which was intended to be relatively flat and quick-cooking. If I just wanted to make a "baked" dessert in it, I'd make brownies instead. (Air fryers are great at brownies, because they're flat, quick-cooking, and benefit from a crispy top.)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can bake a cake in an air fryer. In fact, an air fryer *is* an oven, the name is more of a marketing term.

It may bake slightly differently than in a typical large oven, watch out for it. If in doubt, try a lower temperature, and check diligently for doneness. It might not become perfect cake, but it should be enjoyable.